# Calculation of maximum and minimum and add in the same Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google, normalized-difference-water-index

I want to calculate the maximum value for band 2 and 12 but also the minimum value for band 2 and 12, how can I generate these bands with the new statistics and add them to my ImageCollection to calculate this index.

I have the bands with the values ​​but they are in different ImageCollection and it could not calculate the index.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fpastrana070410%2FCurso_JACK%3ASERIES%20CWI%20GUAJIRA

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
  
}


var Mayo_S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-05-31')
                  .filterBounds(Guajira)
                  .select(['B2','B12','QA60'])
                 // Pre-filtro para imagenes muy nubladas
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 40))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                       
            
Map.addLayer(Mayo_S2)            
print (Mayo_S2)

var S2_max = Mayo_S2 .reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
Map.addLayer(S2_max, {},'SentinalMax')
print(S2_max )

var S2_min = Mayo_S2 .reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
print(S2_min )
Map.addLayer(S2_min,{},'SentinelMin') 


// var CWI = S2_max .expression("(SwirMax * BlueMin) / (BlueMax * SwirMin)", {
//     SwirMax: B12.select ('B12_max'),
//     BlueMin: B2.select('B2_min'),
//     BlueMax: B2.select('B2_max'),
//     SwirMin: B12.select('B12_min')
// } )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can add bands to your image collection:

```
function addBands(image){
  return image.addBands(image.select('B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).rename('B2_max'))
          .addBands(image.select('B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.min()).rename('B2_min'))
          .addBands(image.select('B12').reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).rename('B12_max'))
          .addBands(image.select('B12').reduce(ee.Reducer.min()).rename('B12_min'))}
```

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7629bdedef3aab49fb44ab648b03b7ed

Comment: Thanks friend for your help!  but I have a question. Why do you calculate the statistics of B2 min and B2 Max have the same value? and it happens with B12 min and B12 max            https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fpastrana070410%2FCurso_JACK%3ACWA-MINIMOSYMAXIMOSFINAL

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood your question. You want to get Min and Max value of two bands (B2 and B12), and add them to the map??

Comment: Check this:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/9ce630db631dc0b42215595cd06af663

Comment: Thanks my friend, your code solved my question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please share your repository? Now I am getting this error message

"Cannot load repository.
Repository "users/pastrana070410/Curso_JACK" does not exist
"

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fpastrana070410%2FCurso_JACK%3ASERIES%20CWI%20GUAJIRA